# Hunting memory leaks, VisualVM: "No GC root found". What's next?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, visualvm

I have a memory dump which I has made from a dying application. It has consumed all available heap (-Xmx1024m). It uses `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient` to crawl web pages. Makes a few http requests per minute, dies in several days. As I see from the dump, it has ~1750 instances of `HtmlPage` class, each is with tones of related objects, including full content of a crawled page.

I cannot understand why the `HtmlPage` are not garbage collected. I have investigated instance references and I don't see any my code holding a reference to it, and VisualVM says that "No GC root found". As I understand it should mean the object is eligible for gc, but it doesn't work.

The application is running as a simple standalone process, it doesn't use any web containers or application servers.

Any hints? What else should I look into?

**Specs:**

> - htmlunit v2.7
> - java version "1.6.0_13"
>     Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_13-b03)
>     Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 11.3-b02, mixed mode)
> - Linux my.lan 2.6.18-128.el5 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 11:42:39 EST 2008 i686  i686 i386 GNU/Linux

**Update1**

I have tried to analyse the dump by the YourKit Java Profiler. It shows me a lot of `java.lang.ref.Finalizer` objects with 310mb retained size. They are created for the `net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.NativeGenerator#finalize()` finalizer, and the `NativeGenerator` refers to `Window`, then to `HtmlPage` and to everything.

Does anybody know why are they stay in memory?

*Note*: Curious, but VisualVM showed "pending finalization" as zero.

Comment: Do you have used specific command line arguments for the JVM?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut `-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`

Comment: I'm also experiencing a memory leak with htmlunit 2.8. As a workaround, i re-instantiate WebClient once a day. Hope you can track this bug down.

Comment: I create a new `WebClient` for each request (in sake of thread safety). So, the dump contains nearly the same amount of these instances.

Comment: If you care, you can send us your memory dump. May be we can help. Drop an email to support@plumbr.eu

Comment: Can you post an hprof dump file anywhere?

Comment: @IngoKegel Sorry, I don't think I'm allowed to, it's company internal project... and could contain sensitive information. Also, it's quite big: 250mb compressed size.

Comment: @kan Then try to use a different profiler and check if it also reports "no GC root found"

Comment: @IngoKegel Trying to use the YourKit, updated my question with some news.

Comment: @kan I'm not the expert on Yourkit, please see my user page ;-)

Comment: @IngoKegel the JProfiler works worse than YK, failed with `RuntimeException at 6844153
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 136
 at com.jprofiler.core.D.C.D.?(ejt:1865)
 at com.jprofiler.core.D.C.A.readInt(ejt:2370)
 at com.jprofiler.core.D.F.B.E.?(ejt:1678)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're calling webClient.closeAllWindows() after you're done with page(s) - otherwise JavaScript thread is continuing to run holding references to the page resources etc.

Comment: I have `setJavaScriptEnabled(false)`. Tried to make a small test and seems it works fine even without `closeAllWindows`. But I keep trying...

Comment: I would have thought that only reason to crawl with XmlUnit is to be able to use JavaScript on the pages. Oh well ;)

Comment: Some other pages (crawling in different processes) do use javascript, however this particular app doesn't need it, but crawls more frequently.

Answer (score 2):

When an object has non trivial finalize() method, when creating an instance of the object the JVM creates java.lang.ref.Finalizer that holds reference to the created object so it doesnt get garbage collected before the finalize() method is finished. The memory leak comes from those java.lang.ref.Finalizer-s not being cleared on time. The clearing of these finalizers is done by a separate finalizer daemon thread that has lower priority, so if you create a lot of instances of objects with implemented finalize() method, in time you run out of memory.

Its all described very good in:

http://www.fasterj.com/articles/finalizer2.shtml

This is what they suggest as a solution:

"One obvious way is to increase the priority of the "Finalizer" daemon thread - there is no API for this, so you have to run through all the threads to find it by name, then increase it's priority."

Good luck